# Errors when performing api request to java backend deployed with Google App Engine

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, cors

I'm currently working on my first game application. My frontend is built in Angular, and the backend is in Java. Local tests have been successful, but when deploying to Google App Engine, I encounter issues.

The problem arises when attempting to have the frontend communicate with the backend on Google App Engine. I receive a 504: Gateway Timeout error when doing an API request to one of the endpoints. Locally, everything works fine.

I suspect there's a misconfiguration in Google App Engine, possibly related to the file containing all the endpoints. This file is in a folder called 'api'. Locally, I configure this with a file which implements `ResourceConfig` and includes `packages("dance_game.api")`. The CORS filters are also registered in this file. This file is passed as parameter to the Jetty createServer method, like so:

```
package dance_game;

import java.net.URI;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import dance_game.sources.AppResourceConfig;

public class DanceGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new AppResourceConfig();
        String baseUri = "http://imposter-dance-game.ew.r.appspot.com/";
        JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(URI.create(baseUri), resourceConfig);

        try (Connection connection = DatabaseConnection.getConnection()) {
            System.out.println("Connected to database :D");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As I said this works locally, but now that I have deployed the backend using GAE, this will not work anymore. Instead of this, I added this file implementing the `ServletContainerInitializer` , which also refers to the file containing the endpoints and registers the CORS filters:

```
package dance_game.sources;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

public class JerseyServletContainerInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("JerseyServletContainerInitializer executed");
        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        resourceConfig.packages("dance_game.api");
        resourceConfig.register(CorsFilter.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyServlet", new ServletContainer(resourceConfig));
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/*");
    }
}
```

I don't see the logging from the file in GAE, so I suspect it is not executed. I have also added the file `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`  in resources/META-INF/services and it includes:

```
dance_game.sources.JerseyServletContainerInitializer
```

Am I forgetting something to let this work?  Please ask for more information when needed.